# Installing PHP4 on a Debian (lenny) 7 32bit box

Tags: debian, debian-lenny, php

I am trying to install PHP4 on a Debian 7 32bit box but I ran into the following

```
 root@php4:~# apt-get update
 Get:1 http://snapshot.debian.org lenny Release.gpg [189 B]
 Hit http://snapshot.debian.org lenny Release
 Ign http://snapshot.debian.org lenny Release
 Hit http://snapshot.debian.org lenny/main Sources/DiffIndex
 Hit http://snapshot.debian.org lenny/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
 Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy Release.gpg
 Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg
 Ign http://snapshot.debian.org lenny/main Translation-en_US
 Ign http://snapshot.debian.org lenny/main Translation-en
 Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy Release
 Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release
 Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy/main i386 Packages
 Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en
 Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages
 Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
 Fetched 189 B in 0s (229 B/s)
 Reading package lists... Done
 W: GPG error: http://snapshot.debian.org lenny Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A70DAF536070D3A1
```

I did the following to fix it

```
 gpg --keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys A70DAF536070D3A1
 gpg --export --armor A70DAF536070D3A1 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now I get the following KEYEXPIRED error and unsure how to fix. Even Google does not help

```
 root@php4:~# apt-get update
 Get:1 http://snapshot.debian.org lenny Release.gpg [189 B]
 Hit http://snapshot.debian.org lenny Release
 Ign http://snapshot.debian.org lenny Release
 Hit http://snapshot.debian.org lenny/main Sources/DiffIndex
 Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg
 Hit http://snapshot.debian.org lenny/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
 Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy Release.gpg
 Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release
 Ign http://snapshot.debian.org lenny/main Translation-en_US
 Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy Release
 Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages
 Ign http://snapshot.debian.org lenny/main Translation-en
 Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy/main i386 Packages
 Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
 Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en
 Fetched 189 B in 0s (275 B/s)
 Reading package lists... Done
 W: GPG error: http://snapshot.debian.org lenny Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1246455239
```

Any help?

Comment: Good heavens, why would you be installing that?  Both PHP4 and Lenny are far out of maintenance.  You seem to be trying to mix whezzy and lenny?. Down that road is mafness.

Comment: BTW, the only choice you have, is to disable secure apt.  Debian let the old keys expire, and probably will never be fixing them for an unmaintained release.

Comment: An old script of a client. So I have to run PHP4 on Debian. How to disable secureAPT?

Comment: It would be easier to fix the old script.

Comment: @MichaelHampton its about 200,000 lines of code and client does not want to reinvest. Someone just ripped him off

Comment: I suppose. Just as long as you don't attempt to put it on the Internet.